# Why i cant set my app into root context in jboss ?

Tags: java, jboss

so this is my first time i ask question ,

i got a lil bit problem in my jboss configuration .

im using **jboss 6.2**

**already read this article**

1. http[:]//www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web/jbosswebserver/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7
2. https[:]//developer.jboss[dot]org/wiki/HowdoIoverridethewebcontextroot
3. https[:]//stackoverflow[dot]com/questions/21957060/jboss-deploying-in-root-context

**what i have done ?**

1. create jboss-web.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
> <jboss-web>  
>     <context-root>/</context-root>  
> </jboss-web>
> ```

2. set enable-welcome-content to false in my standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

> ```
>  <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
> ```

3. change myapp.war to ROOT.war and deploy into standalone/deployments/
4. set my welcome-file-list to login.xhtml

> ```
>  <welcome-file-list>
> <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
>  </welcome-file-list>
> ```

and here's the issue is

when request root itself 
192.168.1.98 
 [welcome-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCw4x.jpg)

and when i request 192.168.1.86/login.xhtml

[viola ! it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10whK.jpg)

what i want is when i request just the ip address , it link to login.xhtml .
right now , i have to request my ip + login.xhtml ( 192.168.1.86/login.xhtml )

***then what should i do ?***

need your help guys .

any ideas are welcome .

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is correct.. What you are missing is a index.html (placed in your wars root folder) that redirects to your login page..

When you request 192.168.1.86, your index.html is read.. So, you need to redirect from there to your login page.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <!-- forward to your login -->
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=login.xhtml;charset=utf-8">
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. This still works on Wildfly 21